# Swift 2 Indexing freeze with using array

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift2, xcode7

i had the problem before in swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.x) with array of dictionaries and i have the same problem now in swift 2 (Xcode 7). i added above 37 IBOutlets for building a test Form like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var q1: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var q2: UISegmentedControl!
.
.
.
@IBOutlet weak var q35: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var q36: UISegmentedControl!
```

now for easy accessing and calculating the score i define an array of them like this:

```
var Questions:[UISegmentedControl!]{ return [q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6,q7,q8,q9,q10,q11,q12,q13,q14,q15,q16,q17,q18,q19,q20,q21,q22,q23,q24,q25,q26,q27,q28,q29,q30,q31,q32,q33,q34,q35,q36]}
```

the problem is swift indexing process use 199% of CPU! and it actually freezing and building process get stock!

i'm pretty sure that the problem is with Question array because when i delete it the Xcode just work fine and app will build and run.

is there any way to fix this issue or any better solution?

Comment: An alternative way might be to assign different tags to the `UISegmentedControl` instances, then filter the subviews for `UISegmentedControl` types and get the proper instance by tag. The benefit is you don't need neither an array nor `IBOutlet`s

Comment: @vadian I did think of this idea but the problem is the test is categorized by UITableview and section and ... So it's not easy to accessing them like that!

Comment: Or create them in code from a config, particularly for a table view where you don't need the all all the time

Comment: @Wain can you please give me more details about your idea?

Comment: You can have, for example, a plist file with the questions and answers that you load, and as the table view asks for content dequeue a cell and configure it with the details from the plist - this is the traditional approach rather than creating a static setup in a storyboard